# Magento search by using meta keywords

Tags: magento, meta-key

In my magento store need to make some modifications.

I have a shop by list using meta keywords and also want to search the meta keywords in the top search bar.

The product search works well. I want to implement the meta keyword search in the top search bar. Help me to solve the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to make the meta keywords attribute searchable

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/catalog_product_attribute/index

> Use in Quick Search - Adds this attribute to the list of fields the
>   quick search (the search bar in the header) uses when searching
>
> Use in Advanced Search - Adds this attribute to the list of fields the
>   advanced search uses when searching. Similar to the quick search.
>   However, in the Advanced Search, each attribute will have its own
>   field on the advanced search page, rather than there being one search
>   field